# Making a generator out of an inner function

Tags: python, scope, generator

I would like to extract data from an inner function and build a generator to pass this data somewhere else.

I have the following code:

```py
def process_func(x): 
    # how to construct a generator out of all arguments passed 
    # to this function in the consecutive calls?
    print(f"processing {x}")
    return True


def save_func(x):
    print(f'saving {x}')



# don't edit
def read_data_and_apply_func(func):
    for x in range(5):
        func(x)


# don't edit
def save_data(generator, save_func):
    for i in generator:
        save_func(i)


def main():
    generator = ()  # generator should contain all data passed in all read_data_and_apply_func
    read_data_and_apply_func(process_func)
    save_data(generator, print)


main()
```

how do I edit just the main function (and maybe process_func) so that I can pass the data from the inside of `read_data_and_apply_func` to `save_data`?

I tried writing code like this:

```
def create_generator(read_data_and_apply_func, process_func):
    def generator():
        for x in read_data_and_apply_func(generator.send):
            yield x
    return generator

def main():
    generator = create_generator(read_data_and_apply_func, process_func)
    generator_instance = generator()
    save_data(generator_instance)
```

and a few similar snippets but neither of them worked.

I think the desired output should be:

```
processing 0
saving 0
processing 1
saving 1
processing 2
saving 2
processing 3
saving 3
processing 4
saving 4
```

Comment: This code is very poorly structured, and under the given constraints, you're not going to get anything better than just storing all the data to an intermediate list.

Comment: The concept is flawed.  The comment says "generator should contain all data...", but the whole point of a generator is that it doesn't CONTAIN the data.  It generates each new item, on demand.  This should be reorganized into a pipeline.

Comment: The statement *generator = ()* instantiates an empty tuple

Comment: @TimRoberts I may have not been clear enough, I meant that it should be possible to access all the elements from the `process_func` when iterating over the generator, but not keeping all of them in memory. I understand the code is not clean but I'm wondering whether it's even possible to connect these process/save functions in a reasonable way

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.  This doesn't interleave the output lines.

```
class Holder:
    def __init__(self,hdlr):
        self.data = []
        self.hdlr = hdlr
    def add(self,i):
        self.data.append(i)
        self.hdlr(i)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)

def process_func(x): 
    print(f"processing {x}")
    return True


def save_func(x):
    print(f'saving {x}')


# don't edit
def read_data_and_apply_func(func):
    for x in range(5):
        func(x)


# don't edit
def save_data(generator, save_func):
    for i in generator:
        save_func(i)


def main():
    generator = Holder(process_func)
    read_data_and_apply_func(generator.add)
    save_data(generator, save_func)

main()
```

Comment: nice interface, do you see any way this would be possible to implement this using a generator instead of holding all data in the Holder class? to somehow yield data used in the `process_func` instead of appending to Holder.data

Comment: No.  There has to be a "holding cell" somewhere, because the read process is not directly connected to the save process.  Your `save_data` call is entirely separate, after `read_data_and_apply_func` is completely finished.  Someone has to hold all of the results in between.

Comment: I thought it would be possible to somehow yield the values passed to `process_func`, I tried to rearrange the code in different ways a few times but I wasn't able to get it working. Still I think this should be possible.